# Can I use one Factory to bind viewmodel / repository calls with kodein

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, kodein

In this Factory I need to fetch my data from an api using Retrofit and store the cache with room, my Repository rules this app!
I have repository suspended functions that take care of getting my data and some that save/update data getting and saveing/updating require different values to function and I do not know (yet) how to configure it in Kodein
I lack the experience to solve this and there is nothing I found in Stackoverflow to assist me.

I have tried to add both the variables ID:String and the edited entity (CampaignEntry) to the Definition, it complies but crash on running with

```
No binding found for bind<CampaignEditViewModelFactory>() with ? { String -> ? }
```

My main Application the bind() is crashing the Application

```
class MarketingApplication : Application(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        import(androidXModule(this@MarketingApplication))
...
bind() from factory { id: String, campaignEntry: CampaignEntry -> 
            CampaignEditViewModelFactory(id, campaignEntry, instance()) }
...
```

My ViewModel - having to pass the variables id and campaignEntry that is consumed by different calls in one ViewModel might be the issue - but I cannot figure out the correct solution.

```
class CampaignEditViewModel(
    private val id: String,
    private val campaignEntry: CampaignEntry,
    private val marketingRepository: MarketingRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val campaignToSave by lazyDeferred { marketingRepository.updateCampaign(campaignEntry) }
    val campaignToEdit by lazyDeferred { marketingRepository.getCampaignById(id) }
}
```

my lazyDeferred for clarity

```
fun <T> lazyDeferred(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): Lazy<Deferred<T>> {
    return lazy {
        GlobalScope.async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
            block.invoke(this)
        }
    }
}
```

The Repository snap

```
interface MarketingRepository {
...
    suspend fun getCampaignById(campaignId: String): LiveData<CampaignEntry>
    suspend fun updateCampaign(campaignEntry: CampaignEntry): LiveData<CampaignEntry>
...
```

I call the Viewmodel from my fragment like so

```
class CampaignEditFragment : ScopedFragment(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein by closestKodein()
    private val viewModelFactoryInstanceFactory: ((String) -> CampaignEditViewModelFactory) by factory()
...
private fun bindUI() = launch {
        val campaignVM = campaignEditViewModel.campaignToEdit.await()
...
    btn_edit_save.setOnClickListener {it: View
                saveCampaign(it)
...
private fun saveCampaign(it: View) = launch {
        campaignEditViewModel.campaignToSave.await()
    }
```

And then lastly the ScopedFragment

```
abstract class ScopedFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope {
    private lateinit var job: Job

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        job = Job()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

If you need any more code - please ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are binding with 2 arguments, you need to use `factory2`:

```
private val viewModelFactoryInstanceFactory: ((String, campaignEntry) -> CampaignEditViewModelFactory) by factory2()
```

Comment: Thanx
This solved the problem but also showed me another path, witch I think will be better in  my app, a Path where I use safeArcs to pass the whole Entity record and not only the ID (to get the record from Repository) this way I save a possible delay in a possible re-fetch the data from the Internet and only have the update to do after the edit (if data changed) witch reduce the arguments only back to one :)